# Is scanning a two-dimensional array by subsequent indices not always faster?

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, multidimensional-array

Scanning a two-dimensional array is obviously faster vertically assuming that `x` is first index and `y` is second (due to less cache misses).

However, to my surprise, when I need to scan the array by using vertical stripes (with stripe breadth being 3), **I get results worse by 5% if I process a single stripe vertically than when I do it horizontally**. Could somebody explain me how is that possible?

(**edit**: actually array access in “vertical” method is **indeed faster**, but this method uses **more loops** which slow down the whole thing by more than we gain from less cache misses; see the answer).

*Code below is just an example, but when I benchmarked in BenchmarkDotNet the same approach to scanning arrays in my scanline-fill algorithm implementation, I got same difference in performance.*

Here is my C# benchmark:

```
private void ProcessVerticalStripesHorizontally(int[,] matrix)
{
    int size = matrix.GetLength(0);
    for (int x = 1; x < size - 1; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < size; y++)
        {
            // should be slowe because x is changed often
            var value = matrix[x, y];
            var valueLeft = matrix[x-1, y];
            var valueRight = matrix[x+1, y];
        }
    }
}

private void ProcessVerticalStripesVertically(int[,] matrix)
{
    int size = matrix.GetLength(0);
    for (int x = 1; x < size-1; x++)
    {
        // should be faster because x doesn't change often
        for (int y = 0; y < size; y++)
        {
            var value = matrix[x, y];
        }
        for (int y = 0; y < size; y++)
        {
            var valueLeft = matrix[x - 1, y];
        }
        for (int y = 0; y < size; y++)
        {
            var valueRight = matrix[x + 1, y];
        }
    }
}

[Test]
public void AccessToArrayTest()
{
    int size = 5000;
    var matrix = new int[size, size];
    ProcessVerticalStripesHorizontally(matrix);
    ProcessVerticalStripesVertically(matrix);

    for (int run = 0; run < 5; run++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("run " + run + ": ");

        var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int iteration = 0; iteration < 5; iteration++)
        {
            ProcessVerticalStripesHorizontally(matrix);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("processing stripes horizontally: " 
        + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");

        stopwatch.Restart();
        for (int iteration = 0; iteration < 5; iteration++)
        {
            ProcessVerticalStripesVertically(matrix);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("processing stripes vertically: " 
        + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");
        Console.WriteLine();

    }
}
```

Results:

```
run 0: 
processing stripes horizontally: 454 ms
processing stripes vertically: 468 ms

run 1: 
processing stripes horizontally: 441 ms
processing stripes vertically: 456 ms

run 2: 
processing stripes horizontally: 437 ms
processing stripes vertically: 453 ms

run 3: 
processing stripes horizontally: 437 ms
processing stripes vertically: 456 ms

run 4: 
processing stripes horizontally: 441 ms
processing stripes vertically: 449 ms
```

Comment: That looks like a home-grown benchmark. I don't trust those, especially when it gets down to measuring things like cache misses. Try [BenchmarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/), especially combined with [performance counters](https://adamsitnik.com/Hardware-Counters-Diagnoser/).

Comment: Hi, just as far as I know; bench marking is a pretty complicated thing, with tremendous side effects. For a proper benchmark you should rule out the compiler optimizations and look at the "native" output. If I look at your code, I think the optimizer will try to make the most out of it.

Comment: Having said that: I am not sure how you read your own code and think that, besides the redundant loops, these code pieces are actually different.

Comment: If this code is properly optimized it should be one big no-op because nothing is done with the read values.

Comment: A 5% difference is relatively small. Is there a reason why this difference is significant in your use case?

Comment: Am i the only one who thinks `y` is changing much more often when we put it in 3 different loops and maybe thats why it differs?

Comment: I paste answers on behalf of Павле because he does not have the required reputation yet.
Stefan: I tested these 2 approaches to arrays when creating my scanline-fill algorithm implementation, which I have benchmarked with BenchmarkDotNet. It gave me same difference in results (horizontal being 5% faster). Can you tell me what do you find different in these two pieces of code?
Patrick-Tucci: 5% difference is kind of significant because it's part of a public library which I want to be efficient.
GBursali that's x that has more impact on performance because it's the first index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By analyzing your code I can see that the ProcessVerticalStripesHorizontally method will have a O(n^2) - it will do n*n number of loops.

Meanwhile the ProcessVerticalStripesVertically method will have O(n*3n) - it will do n*n*3 number of loops.

Therefore if your matrix if a 100 x 100 we will have the following:

ProcessVerticalStripesHorizontally  100 * 100 = 10,000 number of loops
ProcessVerticalStripesVertically    100 * 100 * 3 = 30,000 number of loops

Comment: So both are `O(n^2)`, unfortunately you cannot use Big-O notation to explain actual run time performance, only growth.

Comment: You're right that the number of loop passages is different for these cases, but number of accesses to the array is the same (100*100*3 for horizontal method and 100*3*100 for vertical method). Do you suggest that in this case the time of iteration alone is meaningful comparing to time of accessing the array?

Comment: EDIT: Yes, you're right! when I removed array access in my benchmark leaving just empty loops, it turned out that the total time for **“horizontal” method was ~45 ms** and for **“vertical method” was 128 ms**. If we substract these results from total time, it turns out that array access itself is indeed 20% faster in vertical loop, but horizontal method saves much more time doing less iterations.
I just wrongly assumed that iterating is so fast that I can ignore it.

Comment: @Павле: that explains a lot of confusion. Remember all actions are fast. So `var valueLeft = matrix[x - 1, y];` is almost as fast as incrementing your indexer for the loop. Therefore; the loops cannot be ignored. Having said that; I still think an optimizer would create a no-op or single loop out of it.